# Generating nested lists with specified lengths

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested

I want to generate a list of lists that contains a progressive number of randomly generated binary values.

How do I add a condition that tells python to add random values to a list until it reaches a specified length? In this case, the length of each new list should be a progressively larger odd number.

```
from random import randint  

shape = [] 
odds = [x for x in range(100) if x % 2 == 1]

while len(shape) < 300:
    for x in odds:
        randy = [randint(0,1)] * x ??  # need to run this code x amount of times 
        shape.append(randy)            # so that each len(randy) = x
```

*I would prefer to not use count += 1

desired output:

> > > shape
> > >       [[0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1,1,0]...etc]

Comment: You can change `odds = [x for x in range(100) if x % 2 == 1]` to `odds = [x for x in range(1, 100, 2)]`. That uses a range of odd numbers from 1 to 100 (2 is the `step` or interval).

Comment: +1 good point. I'll use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a <s>*generator expression*</s> *list comprehension*:

```
randy = [randint(0, 1) for i in range(x)]
```

The problem with `[someFunc()] * someNum` is that Python first evaluates the inner expression, `someFunc()` and resolves it to some number before executing the outer expression.

Comment: nicely done.. so is this actually a list comprehension with a predicate?